# Glyph origin of the character for frequency 频/頻 = steps + head?

Tags: glyph-origin, character-components

What's the story behind this character 频? Neither of its components contribute phonetically to it, yet I can't seem to relate any of its components 步 steps and head/face 页 to its meaning of frequent/repeated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

「頻」 was created from omitting 「氵・水」 from 「瀕・」. While 「瀕」 remained as a character used for its original meaning, the newly created 「頻」 was used as a phonetic loan meaning *frequent*.

---

| 時期 字體 | 字形 | 參考資料 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [西周](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_Zhou) [金](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bronze_inscriptions) | [image: 瀕] | 㝬簋 [集成4317](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=4317&jgwfl=) |
| [戰國](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warring_States_period)・[楚](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_of_Chu) [簡](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bamboo_and_wooden_slips) | [image] | 壹・皇門5 [清華戰簡](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsinghua_Bamboo_Slips) |
| [篆](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_seal_script) | [image] | [頻部](https://ctext.org/library.pl?if=gb&file=77391&page=124) [說文解字](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuowen_Jiezi) |
| [秦](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qin_dynasty) 陶文 | [image] | 263 古陶文字徵 |
| 秦 陶文 | [image: 頻] | 263 古陶文字徵 |
| [西漢](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Han_dynasty#Western_Han) [璽印](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seal_(East_Asia)) | [image: 頻] | 漢印文字徵 |
| [東漢](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Han_dynasty#Eastern_Han) [隸](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clerical_script) | [image: 頻] | 陰面 [華嶽廟殘碑](https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-hk/%E8%8F%AF%E5%B1%B1%E5%BB%9F%E7%A2%91) |
| [楷](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_script) | [image: 頻] |  |

<kbd>[image: 瀕]</kbd>
　
<kbd>[image: 瀕]</kbd>

「頻」 was originally 「瀕」 ([*riverbank*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bank_(geography))), comprised of semantic [「涉」 (*picture of feet/footprints next to a body of water*](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=32636) > *to wade across water*) and semantic [「頁」 (*picture of a person with an exaggerated head/eye*)](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=1498).

<kbd>[image]</kbd>
　
<kbd>[image]</kbd>
　
<kbd>[image]</kbd>

The 「水」 part of 「涉」 was often written in the middle of 「步」, leading to the side-by-side structure 「⿰頁」 instead.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>
　
<kbd>[image: 頻]</kbd>
　
<kbd>[image: 頻]</kbd>
　
<kbd>[image: 頻]</kbd>
　
<kbd>[image: 頻]</kbd>

The side-by-side structure was prone to corruption. More specifically, 「水」 tended to be squeezed out and omitted, forming 「頻」.

---

From this, we can see that 「頻」 is just a shape variant of 「瀕」, and originally shared the same definition as 「瀕」. From the [*Classic of Poetry: Major Court Hymns: Decade of Dàng*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classic_of_Poetry#Contents_list):

> #### 《詩經・大雅・召旻》
>
> 池之竭矣、不云自**頻**。
> 泉之竭矣、不云自中。
> 溥斯害矣、職兄斯弘、不烖我躬。
>
> *A pool becomes dry; is it not because no water comes to it from its **banks**?*
>
> *A spring becomes dry; is it not because no water rises in it from itself?*
>
> *Great is the injury [all about]. So that my anxious sorrow is increased. Will not calamity light on my person?*
>
> <sub>Translation by [James Legge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Legge). See https://ctext.org/book-of-poetry/decade-of-dang.</sub>

Later on, while 「瀕」 remained in use as a character representing the word meaning *riverbank*, the differentiated character 「頻」 started becoming solely used as a phonetic loan character meaning *frequent*.

---

**References:**

- [漢語多功能字庫](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/)
- 季旭昇《說文新證》
- [小學堂字形演變](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian)
- [國學大師](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/)

  - [郭沫若《甲骨文合集》](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/)
  - [中國社會科學院考古研究所《殷周金文集成》](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/)
- [中國哲學書電子化計劃](https://ctext.org/)

  - [宋・徐鉉等奉敕校定　漢・許慎《說文解字》](https://ctext.org/library.pl?if=gb&res=77351)

Comment: It's interesting how in [this instance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBj9n.png), the left and right components got swapped places.

Answer (score 0):

频 is simplefield Chinese. 頻 is traditional Chinese.

步 means step and 页 means head in ancient Chinese.
频 is explained as "Nod your head for each step." literally. It extended meaning to "frequent" or "repeat". Imagining that you are frequenting/repeating noding your head for each step.